# SQL Count function won't work on joined query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Got two tables.

Artist:ArtistID,ArtistFirstName,ArtistLastName,ArtistEmail,ArtistPhone,Biography,ReferenceNumber,AgentID

Agent:AgentID,AgentFirstName,AgentLastName,CompanyName,AgentEmail,AgentPhone

Trying to list the number of artists represented by each booking agent

note: an agent can represent many artists but each artist got one agent only.

This is what I got and not sure why it is not working, Thanks

```
SELECT ag.AgentFirstName,ag.AgentLastName,ag.CompanyName,ag.AgentID,COUNT 
(ar.ArtistID) AS NumberOfArtists
FROM Agent ag
JOIN Artist ar ON ar.AgentID  = ag.AgentID
GROUP BY ArtistID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aggregating by the wrong column.  You need to aggregate by the agent:

```
SELECT ag.AgentFirstName, ag.AgentLastName, ag.CompanyName, ag.AgentID, 
       COUNT(ar.ArtistID) AS NumberOfArtists
FROM Agent ag JOIN
     Artist ar
     ON ar.AgentID  = ag.AgentID
GROUP BY ag.AgentFirstName, ag.AgentLastName, ag.CompanyName, ag.AgentID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ag.AgentFirstName, ag.AgentLastName, ag.CompanyName, ag.AgentID,
       COUNT(ar.ArtistID) AS NumberOfArtists
FROM Agent ag
JOIN Artist ar ON ar.AgentID = ag.AgentID
GROUP BY ag.AgentFirstName, ag.AgentLastName, ag.CompanyName, ag.AgentID
```